# Gitlab CI - how to list directory that changes and put it in a pipeline variable

Tags: variables, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

Is it possible to automatically detect the top-level directory that contains file that have changes in the commit, and add this to a variable that i can use in another stage ?

Let's say i have a project with :

- folder1/file[1-3].txt
- folder2/folder3/file4.txt

If the commit modify file1.txt, i would like to define a variable that is equal to "folder1".

```
   variables:
   - $MYVAR == "folder1"
```

If the commit modify file4.txt, i would like to define a variable that is equal to "folder2".

```
   variables:
   - $MYVAR == "folder2"
```

Modification to multiple file in different folder should not happen.

And then use that variable in another stage of the pipeline :

```
MEP:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo $MYVAR
```

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditionally define variables with `rules:variables:` -- rules can use `rules:changes:` to determine if particular files changed.

```yaml
myjob:
  variables:
    MY_VAR: "default value"

  rules:
    - changes:
        - folder1/file[1-3].txt
      variables:
        MY_VAR: folder1  # override MY_VAR when this rule matches
    - changes:
        - folder2/folder3/file4.txt
      variables:
        MY_VAR: folder2
```

Keep in mind only 1 rule matches for any given job/pipeline.